# Weird bug while allocating memory for struct members

Tags: c, struct, malloc

The program below does not print the expected output:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct {
    char *keyword;
    char *keyword2;
} my_struct;

int main(void) {

    char str[] = "keyword1,key word 2,keyword3,keyword 4";
    my_struct *pstr = NULL;
    int i, count;
    char *pch;

    // String break
    pch = strtok(str, ",");
    for (i = 0; pch != NULL; i++) {
        pstr = realloc (pstr, (i+1)*sizeof(my_struct *));
        pstr[i].keyword = malloc (strlen(pch) + 1);
        strcpy(pstr[i].keyword, pch);
        pch = strtok (NULL, ",");
    }
    count=i;

    // Print values
    for (i=0; i<count; i++) {
        printf("%d: %s\n", i, pstr[i].keyword);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
0: p`�
1: key word 2
2: (null)
3: keyword 4
```

However if I remove "char *keyword2" from "my_struct" everything works fine:

```
0: keyword1
1: key word 2
2: keyword3
3: keyword 4
```

Can anybody explain to me why this happens?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I guess that `sizeof(my_struct *)` will return size or a pointer. You need to use `sizeof(my_struct)`.

It work in case then you remove `char *keyword2;` because size of a structure becomes equal to size of a pointer (structure holds one pointer).

Answer (score 1):

Try changing

```
sizeof(my_struct *)
```

to

```
sizeof(my_struct )

                ^^ no asterisk
```